# Open Bootstrap modal from code behind

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to open the bootstrap modal from the code behind. However, when I click the button the alert message comes up but the modal never shows up on the page. I have already looked at other questions but none work for me. Please is there anything that I am missing?

ASPX page

```
<asp:Content runat="server" ID="BodyContent" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent">
    <script src="~/Scripts/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script src="~/Scripts/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
    <script src="~/Scripts/bootstrap.js"></script>
    <script src="~/Scripts/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
         function openModal() {
             alert('hiii');
             $('#myModal').modal('show');
         }          
    </script>


    <div id="myModal" class="modal fade" role="dialog" runat="server">
        <div class="modal-dialog">

        <!-- Modal content-->
            <div class="modal-content">
                <div class="modal-header">
                    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
                    <h4 class="modal-title">Modal Header</h4>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-body">
                    <p>Some text in the modal.</p>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-footer">
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                </div>
            </div>

        </div>
     </div>

    <div>
        <asp:Button runat="server" ID="btnUploadFile" Text="Upload File" OnClick="btnUploadFile_OnClick" class="btn standard-gradient disabled" />
    </div>
</asp:Content>
```

Code Behind

```
protected void btnUploadFile_OnClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, this.GetType(), "Pop", "openModal();", true);
}
```

Comment: Server naming convention, your `myModal` is attributed with `runat="server"`, try to use `$('#<%=myModal.ClientID%>').modal('show');`

Comment: If you trigger openModal() from javascript; does the model show?

Comment: @haraman I tried that but no luck

Comment: @MarcusH I will check

Answer (score 0):

I  have a master page Default.aspx with layout:

```
<html>
     <head>
            <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../Styles/bootstrap.min.css" />   
     <script src="../js/bootstrap.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script> 
     </head>
    <body>
        <input type="hidden" runat="server" value="" id="hiddenAlert" name="hiddenAlert" clientidmode="Static" />
    ………….
    <div class="modal modalMain fade" id="myModalMain" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true" style="overflow-y: hidden;">
        <div class="modal-dialog" style="position: relative; top: 25%; left: 0%; width: 300px;">
            <div class="modal-content">
                <div class="modal-header">
                    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                        <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                    </button>
                </div>
                <div id="modalBody" class="modal-body modal-body-main">
                    ...
                </div>
                <div class="modal-footer" style="margin-top: 0px; padding: 5px; text-align: center;">
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Ok</button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    if ($('#hiddenAlert').val() != '') {
        $('.modal-body-main').html($('#hiddenAlert').val());
        $('.modalMain').modal('show');

    }
</script>

     </body>
</html>
```

And in codebedind:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    ………..
    string alert = this.Request["alert"];
            if(alert == "success")
                hiddenAlert.Value = "Data saved successfull";
            else
                hiddenAlert.Value = "Data saved fail";
}
```

And in a other page , I have a form and a submit button

```
<asp:Button ID="btnLuu" runat="server" Text="Lưu" CssClass="input" onclick="btnLuu_Click"/>
```

In codebedind:

```
protected void btnLuu_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    ….//save your data
    //if save successful
    Response.Redirect("Default.aspx?Module=" + cModule + "&l=" + language_id + "&p=" + p + "&alert=success");

}
```

So, you can show any alert content : success, fail or exist data … with a modal pop up for all of pages in your website.